# PHP modules explanation

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, nginx

I have question about PHP modules that I can't understand very well how they work and I will appreciate your help.

If I have installed mod_php7 and the package contains php7, mod_php7 and php7-zts I assume that php7 are the main php files (correct me if I am wrong).

I did a lot of reading and found out that mod_php, php-fpm and FastCGI are modules for PHP that can be used.

If I install php7-fpm it doesnt include same extensions as mod_php7. My question is Do I have to install php7 and php7-zts and then install php7-fpm to make PHP work?

Another question is If I have already installed mod_php7 package that includes php7, mod_php7 and php7-zts, can I install php7-fpm and replace mod_php?

And do Apache and php-fpm work well or Nginx and php-fpm is better?

Answer (score 0):

Some php features are dependent on how/which webserver you are using and how you install/configure php.  A good example of this is running the php files as the user/group that owns them instead of as the user the webserver runs as (www-data, etc).

A really succinct overview of mod_php vs fastcgi vs php-fpm is available here - http://fastjoomlahost.com/mod_php-fastcgi-php-fpm-server

Yes, I know answers belong here, but I'd have to copy/paste the entire article and that would be copyright violation. I did check and the link is available in archive.org so I'm fairly sure it will remain available...

Comment: It wouldn't be too difficult to summarise that article and include the most important information in your answer.